# Binding text via ToolTip to specific ComboBox Item with the use of TextBlock C# MVVM XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, combobox, tooltip

I want to bind ToolTipText property to the ToolTip its self so it can display some text information for every ComboBoxItem. Unfortunately I only get blank TextBlock and this error in the Output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error:
>   'ToolTipText' property not found on 'object' ''Double'
>   (HashCode=1076756480)'. BindingExpression:Path=ToolTipText;
>   DataItem='Double' (HashCode=1076756480); target element is 'TextBlock'
>   (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

**ComboBox:**

```
<ComboBox Name="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LiniaWyComboBox, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsEditable="True"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          Text="{Binding Prad_pojemnosciowy, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          PreviewKeyDown="PradPojemnosciowyComboBox_OnPreviewKeyDown">

          <ComboBox.Style>
           <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
               <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox}"/>
             </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
         </ComboBox.Style>

        <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
          <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
           <EventSetter Event="MouseMove"  Handler="OnMouseHover" />
             <Setter Property="ToolTip">
               <Setter.Value>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ToolTipText , RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                 </TextBlock>
                </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
               </Style>
             </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   </ComboBox>
```

**Method - OnMouseHover:**

```
 private void OnMouseHover (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var lineSelected = (modelGPZ.GetLineWyList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSelected == true));
        ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
        if ((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0])
        {
            //ToolTipTextList.Add("FirstItem");
            ToolTipText = "ONE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
            OnPropertyChanged("LiniaWyComboBox");
            OnPropertyChanged("ToolTipText");
        }
        else
        {
            //ToolTipTextList.Add("SecondItem");
            ToolTipText = "TWO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!";
            OnPropertyChanged("LiniaWyComboBox");
            OnPropertyChanged("ToolTipText");
        }

    }
```

**ToolTipText:**

```
        private string _toolTipText;
    public string ToolTipText
    {
        get { return _toolTipText; }
        set {
            if (_toolTipText!=value)
            {
                _toolTipText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ToolTipText");
            }
            else
            {
                _toolTipText = "";
            }
        }

   }
```

**DataGrid:**

```
<DataGrid Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" 
Grid.Row="1" 
VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
SelectedIndex="0" 
Name="LinieWyDatagrid"  
ItemsSource="{Binding LiniaWyComboBox, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
CanUserAddRows="False" 
CanUserDeleteRows="False" 
CanUserSortColumns="True" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False"
ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
SelectionChanged="LinieWyDatagrid_SelectedCellsChanged"
SelectionMode="Single">
```

Comment: How and where ToolTipText is declared? What is the value of DataContext?

Comment: I've updated the post with the ToolTipText declaration. The value of DataContext when I hover over ComboBoxItem is .. null.. hmm. What do you mean what is the value of it?

Comment: Doesn't it work if you delete the RelativeSource part? I think this way you try to bind ComboBox's ToolTipText property which obviously does not exist.

Comment: unfortunately not.. that's the problem. Binding error exists now or then

Comment: And if you add `DataContext = this` after `InitializeComponent()` ?

Comment: doesn't work this way too. I've tried to add DataContext=this in OnMouseHover method and I still get a blank textblock when hovering over the items. I know the string property ToolTipText changes whatever I put my mouse on. From doing some intense resarch.. is this about how the ComboBox is Binded? The mentioned error is about unable to find the property *ToolTipText* on the object 'Double'. I've added a snippet of my DataGrid Binding too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to work this out. The property 'ToolTipText' is not needed. Here is the edited code:

**XAML ComboBox:**

...

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle >
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
  <EventSetter Event="UIElement.MouseMove"  Handler="OnMouseHover"/>
 </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

...

**OnMouseHover:**

```
private void OnMouseHover (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  var lineSelected = (modelGPZ.GetLineWyList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.isSelected == true));
   ComboBoxItem item = sender as ComboBoxItem;
   if ((double)item.Content == lineSelected.LiniaWyComboBox[0])
   {
    item.ToolTip = "Item number one";
    }
    else
    {
     item.ToolTip = "Item number two";
     }
    }
```